# How to get a Gradle detached configuration to use a resolution strategy from the dependency-lock plugin?

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-plugin

We are using the [gradle-dependency-lock-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin). A global.lock file is generated, containing a list of all the dependencies used by our project.

In one of our Gradle tasks, a detached configuration is created and used to resolve an artifact. What I noticed is that it resolves it to the latest version in Nexus, and not to the version in the global.lock file.

For example, global.lock contains some-library-10.0.0-ci.3 but the resolved artifact is at some-library-10.0.0-ci.5.

This appears to be a known problem with detached configurations - they don't use the resolution strategy - as discussed [here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Detached-configuration-to-copy-ResolutionStrategy-td5713025.html).

I was reading the source code of the dependency-lock plugin, and it appears to set the resolutionStrategy for all configurations in DependencyLockPlugin.groovy's applyLock method:

```
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force lockForces.toArray()
    }
}
```

I was hoping to set the resolution strategy of the detached configuration doing this:

```
def dep = dependencies.create( elastic( "$notation:$version" ) )
def detachedConf = configurations.detachedConfiguration( dep ).setTransitive( false )
detachedConf.resolutionStrategy {
    configurations.all.resolutionStrategy
}
def resolvedArtifacts = detachedConf.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts
assert resolvedArtifacts.size() == 1 : 'Only one artifact should be present'
def resolvedArtifact
resolvedArtifacts.each { resolvedArtifact = it }
```

However, Gradle complains with:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'resolutionStrategy' on configuration container.
```

I switched it to use configurations.default.resolutionStrategy and configurations.compile.resolutionStrategy, but in either case it continued to access the latest version from Nexus.

How do I properly set the resolution strategy of the detached configuration so that it uses the same resolution strategy as set by the dependency-lock plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution entailed setting the forcedModules of the detached configuration's resolution strategy to one of the other configurations:

```
detachedConf.resolutionStrategy.forcedModules = configurations.install.resolutionStrategy.forcedModules
```

*install* is the configuration we use for accessing resolved artifacts, but it could be any of the other configurations since they all use the same resolution strategy.